# Distribute No Modify License

Tags: licensing

I would like to release some code and some documentation to be distributed freely, but not if it has been modified in any way. Basically, needs to be shared "as-is". The reason is I would like to retain control of all modifications without making it it closed source. Is there a commonly available license that allows for this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515535/software-licensing-open-source-no-commerical-no-derivatives

Comment: I am happy for it to be distributed for any purpose, commercial or otherwise as long as that is without modification and with full attribution. I am not concerned about others making profits through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Creative Commons "Attribution No Derivatives (BY-ND) license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/3.0/)" is what you want? Otherwise check the [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org) website, it has a license chooser application that helps in selecting the correct license.